# How to upload a file to AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating a simple application where I want to upload a file to my AWS S3 bucket. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;

public class UploadFileInBucket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clientRegion = "<myRegion>";
        String bucketName = "<myBucketName>";
        String stringObjKeyName = "testobject";
        String fileObjKeyName = "testfileobject";
        String fileName = "D:\\Attachments\\LICENSE";

        try {

            BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("<myAccessKey>", "<mySecretKey>");
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                    .build();

            // Upload a text string as a new object.
            s3Client.putObject(bucketName, stringObjKeyName, "Uploaded String Object");

            // Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType("plain/text");
            metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle");
            request.setMetadata(metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(request);
        }
        catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to upload a file and getting an error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: 

    ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS
        at com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader.<clinit>(PartitionsLoader.java:52)
        at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionMetadataFactory.create(RegionMetadataFactory.java:30)
        at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.initialize(RegionUtils.java:64)
        at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionMetadata(RegionUtils.java:52)
        at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegion(RegionUtils.java:105)
        at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.getRegionObject(AwsClientBuilder.java:249)
        at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.withRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:238)
        at UploadFileInBucket.main(UploadFileInBucket.java:28)
```

I have added required AWS bucket credentials, permissions and dependencies to execute this code.

What changes I should made in the code to get my file uploaded to desired bucket?

Comment: Are you running this code locally, and how did you include the AWS dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I am running it locally and added all required dependencies.

Comment: If its a maven application run `maven update`

Comment: No, actually it's not maven.

Comment: Did you have `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`'s jar file in your class path

Comment: Yes, already added it.

Comment: Why jackson dependency in your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you either have the wrong version of the Jackson libraries or are somehow linking with multiple versions of them.

The AWS for Java SDK distribution contains a third-party/lib directory which contains all of the (correct versions of) the libraries that version of the SDK should be built with. Depending on which features of the SDK you are using you may not need all of them, but those are the specific 3rd party libraries you should be using.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Jackson to your classpath. Its classes are missing.
I don't know which version you need, but you can download them from their gitpage: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/

Comment: Already added the dependency for the same.Still having same issue.Any suggestion please?

Comment: The exception says the Jackson class cannot be found. Your application cannot find the dependencies. Can you edit your question and add 1) your folder/file structure and 2) how you are running the application. I will then edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, updated the dependencies. Currently having an issue with 'Mutator'. Please refer updated question.Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is described in this ticket: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues/12